# Weak convergence of scaled elements implies norm convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $u_{k}\in l^2{\mathbb{(Z)}}$ be a sequence such that for every sequence $n_{k} \in \mathbb{Z}$ the sequence $n_{k}u_{k}\rightharpoonup 0$. Prove that $ u_{k} \rightarrow 0$ in $l^{q}(\mathbb{Z}) , 2 <q \leq \infty$.

#### Progress

I am trying to show that $\sum_{n} u_{n}^{k} - n_{k}{\phi}_{n} \rightarrow 0$ but I can't.  Here $\{ u_{n} : n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ are the distributions and  $\{{\phi}_{n} : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ are their respective characteristic functions.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I am trying to show that $\sum_{n} u_{n}^{k} - n_{k}{\phi}_{n} \rightarrow 0$ but I can't. Do you have any idea?

Comment: What's $u_n^k$ and what's $\phi_n$?

Comment: Let $\{ u_{n} : n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ are the distributions and let $\{{\phi}_{n} : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ be their respective characteristic functions.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

1. Recall that every weakly convergent sequence is bounded in the norm.
2. Think of what it means for $n_{k}u_{k}$ to be bounded in the norm **for every** sequence $n_k$
3. Conclude that your sequence $u_k$ is very special.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean.May you please explain in more details?

Comment: @Angela If $u_k\ne 0$ for infinitely many $k$, then by choosing  $n_k>k/\|u\|_k$ for all such $k$ you get that $n_k u_k$ is unbounded, and therefore is not weakly convergent.

Comment: Yes!It is very clear what you mean now.Thank you!